# How to perform a clean re-installation due to dll errors

Tags: qgis

Following a virus, Qgis won't run and errors saying missing dll.  I manually replaced the first missing dll but it now complains about a second one.  I suspect that if I simply replace this one it will just keep complaining about them all.
I have tried to remove and reinstall Qgis but this didn't fix the problem.
Is there a way to clean de-install?
Or a quick way to replace all the dlls?
Thanks
Graham

Comment: That depends on which DLLs are missing or corrupt. Since you tried a reinstall of QGIS already, it sounds like there may be something more important missing (unfortunately). DLL names would help us determine if that is the case.

Comment: Hi, the first dll is sqlite3.  The error message reads: "The procedure entry point sqlite3_open_v2 could not be located in the dynamic link library sqlite3.dll".  We manually replaced this dll and then it complained about mozcrt19.dll saying: "The program can't start because MOZCRT19.dll is missing from your computer. Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.  I suspect that if we replace this dll it will ask for another, then another etc.

Comment: Good, these two aren't system ones. If you were using the standalone installer for QGIS, you could try with the OSGEO4W package, which also comes with all the dependencies bundled. http://trac.osgeo.org/osgeo4w/

Comment: Hi, we downloaded that version, but it just wouldn't work, giving a mount and access denied error.  In the end we downloaded a different version () which works but gives an error:

Comment: Hi, we downloaded that version, but it just wouldn't work, giving a mount and access denied error.  In the end we downloaded a different version (QGIS Dufour 2.0.1) which works but gives an error first:  Runtime Error R6034 (https://www.dropbox.com/s/h0pitcgcxpzg3mb/Capture.JPG).  I found Bug #8629 and followed the fix in changeset c797895ca7ceb558b7811b88f764c89e6fd278b6 (http://hub.qgis.org/projects/quantum-gis/repository/revisions/c797895ca7ceb558b7811b88f764c89e6fd278b6) but it didn't work.  Can you suggest what I can try next please? Thanks